# How to modify only the existing key of a hashmap but not its pair?

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

data.put("AAA", "CCC");
```

I want to replace `AAA` with `BBB` during run-time without adding a new key into the `map`.
Is this possible?

Comment: No, because it does not make sense.

Comment: Hashmap key is immutable, you wont be able to replace the key..you can remove "AAA" and add "BBB" and value

Comment: Maybe explain why you want to do that and we will propose a more adapted data structure. If "CCC" is fixed and "AAA" can be changed to "BBB", maybe you should inverse the Map in order to make "CCC" the key and "AAA" its associated value.

Comment: If you change a key from "AAA" to "BBB", it will have a different hashcode, and will need to be stored in a different place in the hashmap. Changing the key without removing/adding is not only impossible, it would break the hashmap if it were possible.

Comment: Key’s hash code is used primarily in conjunction to its equals() method, for putting a key in map and then searching it back from map. So if hash code of key object changes after we have put a key-value pair in map, then its almost impossible to fetch the value object back from map. It is a case of memory leak. ref: https://interviewsmadeeasy.wordpress.com/category/why-hashmap-key-must-be-immutable/

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I am using keys of Field from Web UI label name(Product Name, Product Description) but its backend field names are without spaces (ProductName, ProductDescription). So i wanna edit only the keys without affecting its value. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @HifzurRahman Your key is conceptually the same but in a different form. You should normalize it. If I were you, I think I would normalize the key (i.e. deleting spaces) *before* inserting the key/value in the map.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle That was just the example, not only spaces there might be some symbols also be present. Thank you! I wanted to know whether there is another way to do it. I got the answer now. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

### You can't*

There is **no*** way to edit existing key, the only way is to remove the old one and add a new key. 
The most elegant way to do it (IMHO) is this:

```
map.put( "newKey", map.remove( "oldKey" ) );
```

*: As @Michael Ziluck say in his comment and answer, you could technically do it with reflection, but as it destroy the integrity of HashTable, you should only do it at your own risk

Comment: It is possible with reflection. Changing almost anything is possible with reflection.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck Technically speaking, it is possible but you shall not do that.

Comment: Isn't that some kind of hacking? I mean, with reflection, can't you also bypass private/protected variables?

Comment: It breaks the integrity of the hash table, but there are times when people want to use a map implementation and `HashMap` is just the easiest one to use. If you 1. Need a `Map` implementation 2. Don't care about the hash table, and 3. Don't want to write an implementation yourself, using reflection to hack at the keys of a `HashMap` is fine.

Comment: " How can I edit an immutable object - By changing the rules so it's not immutable anymore" doesn't seems to be a good practice for me, better make your own implementation. I agree that you could do it, but I don't think you should

Comment: Absolutely I don't think you should. But the question was if you CAN not if you SHOULD. It does sound like the argument from The Office where "what's the safest way to ski? don't ski!", but in reality it is more like "what's the safest way to ski? ski on a planet with very little gravity". Not the most practical answer, and you probably shouldn't do that in either situation, but it is POSSIBLE to do.

Comment: @Kepotx this is dangerous. if `oldKey` is not present `newKey` key will contain `null` as value

Answer (score 2):

Just delete old pair. Make a new pair with the new key and do insert.

Comment: Is it not possible without using data.remove("AAA")?

Comment: Using the `Map`-API it is possible. Assuming `map` is a `HashMap` you can get `it = map.keySet().iterator()`. But you still have to identify the key while iterating. Once identified you can use `it.remove()`. This will remove the entry as `map.remove(o)` would do.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to rename/change the old key of a pair - buzzword `immutable`. You need to remove the object and insert it back with a new key.
Here is how it works in detail:

```
HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("AAA", "CCC");
String value = map.remove("AAA");  // value = "CCC"
map.put("BBB", value);
```

Of cause you can shortern it to a oneliner like removing the value while setting it. Because remove wwhile return the value.
`map.put("BBB", map.remove("AAA"))`

Comment: Nothing in Java is truly immutable. Even Strings can be changed with reflection. In case you want to say "yeah that's technically true, but..." he did ask if you "can" not if you "should".

Comment: @MichaelZiluck you´re right but you realy know what I mean^^

Comment: Yep, just want to be clear in case he is actually interested in hacking around with reflection :)

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap`s are based around hashing the keys, and assuming that the keys never change. For that reason, changing them will break the integrity of the hash table and you will lose all efficiency.

That being said, there IS technically a way to change the key. You would need to look at the source code for the `HashMap` class and then use reflection to directly edit the key itself.